# Generic plural noun vs. singular indefinite noun vs. definite noun, which is more general?

Tags: articles, definite-article, plural-forms, indefinite-article, generic-noun-phrases

Consider this sentence by me

> Considering these issues, today, there is a trend toward using document understanding and spatial reasoning to capture the conceptual structure of **(a web page/web pages/ the page)**

Considering context *the page* can refer to a web page (?). Now, my question is which of these make the sentence more general? I mean when you speak in general you prefer to say, for example, **babies** or **a baby** or **the baby** in

> Babies usually cry almost two hours a day.
>
> A baby usually cries almost two hours a day.
>
> The baby usually cries almost two hours a day. Don't panic.

---

Another example:

> We simulate the way a human user scans **a web page/the page** to find specific data.

Comment: I think you can add "the babies", too

Answer (score 1):

> Considering these issues, today, there is a trend toward using document understanding and spatial reasoning to capture the conceptual structure of *a web page*.

-- tells me we're talking of any web page, and, essentially, all of them.

> Considering these issues, today, there is a trend toward using document understanding and spatial reasoning to capture the conceptual structure of *web pages*.

-- now, this one strangely talks of capturing the structure of more than one page (at a time?).  I think it's because '*structure*' is singular and '*pages*' is plural.

> Considering these issues, today, there is a trend toward using document understanding and spatial reasoning to capture the conceptual structure of *the page*.

-- can probably used interchangeably with the first, since your entire article is about **web** pages.  An alternative composition is

> Considering... to capture the *page* conceptual structure.

(although it's probably no better, especially because it's unclear what 'the' defines, the *page* or the *structure*).

Answer (score 0):

With no article is the most general.

> Web pages

That's not to say that in the right context, using an article **isn't** general. In your sentence about **a** baby, I would argue that that is more or less as general as **babies**. On the other hand, **the** generally narrows us down to something more specific.

> The baby (the one lying in front of us) usually cries almost two hours a day.

So, in short, I think you're best off using **web pages** if your objective is to be general:

> ... to capture the conceptual structure of **web pages** (generally)

Though the other options are entirely valid too:

> ... to capture the conceptual structure of **a web page** (e.g. like the one we're going to see as an example in just a second)
>
> ... to capture the conceptual structure of **the page** (e.g. we showed you in the previous tutorial)

Just not as good if generality is your goal.

Comment: In the choices given there is no "**the web page**", only "**the page**".

Comment: Semantics, sir!